# Trigger Dask workers to release memory

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm distributing the computation of some functions using Dask. My general layout looks like this:

```py
    from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster, as_completed

    cluster = LocalCluster(processes=config.use_dask_local_processes,
                           n_workers=1,
                           threads_per_worker=1,
                           )
    client = Client(cluster)
    cluster.scale(config.dask_local_worker_instances)

    work_futures = []

    # For each group do work
    for group in groups:
        fcast_futures.append(client.submit(_work, group))

    # Wait till the work is done
    for done_work in as_completed(fcast_futures, with_results=False):
        try:
            result = done_work.result()
        except Exception as error:
            log.exception(error)
```

My issue is that for a large number of jobs I tend to hit memory limits. I see a lot of:

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process memory: 1.15 GB -- Worker memory limit: 1.43 GB
```

It seems that each future isn't releasing its memory. How can I trigger that? I'm using dask==1.2.0 on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Results are help by the scheduler so long as there is a future on a client pointing to it. Memory is released when (or shortly after) the last future is garbage-collected by python. In your case you are keeping all of your futures in a list throughout the computation. You could try modifying your loop:

```
for done_work in as_completed(fcast_futures, with_results=False):
    try:
        result = done_work.result()
    except Exception as error:
        log.exception(error)    
    done_work.release()
```

or replacing the `as_completed` loop with something that explicitly removes futures from the list once they have been processed.

Comment: I'm trying to find the `release()` API documented. I'm not seeing it under concurrent.futures or in Dask distributed. Am I missing it somehow?

Comment: Not documented and partially "internal" https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/client.py#L358

Comment: If one is returning None from the tasks, should there be any memory usage when futures are kept (just the status and some metadata is kept?)

Comment: Yes, the concrete object is still held on a worker, together with some entries in that worker's internal dictionaries which reference it.