# How to store data from dask.distributed on disk?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, zarr

I'm trying to scale my computations from local Dask Arrays to Dask Distributed.
Unfortunately, I am new to distributed computed, so I could not adapt the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66769922/concurrently-write-xarray-datasets-to-zarr-how-to-efficiently-scale-with-dask) for my purpose.

Mainly my problem is saving data from distributed computations back to an in-memory Zarr array while using Dask chaching and graph optimization process to get some statistics of the array back as well.

I want to preprocess some data, including subtracting one reference row and the row-wise mean. Doing this looks straightforward only with Dask arrays:

```py
# create toy data
zarry = zarr.open('./example.zarr', mode='w')
sample_data = zarry.create_group("sample_data", overwrite=True)
s1 = sample_data.create_dataset('sample1', shape=(5, 1_000), chunks=(5, 100), dtype=int)
s1[:,:] = np.random.randint(0, 100, (5, 1_000))
data = da.from_zarr(s1)
analysed = zarry.create_group("analysed_data", overwrite=True)
r1 = analysed.create_dataset('analysed1', shape=(5, 1_000), chunks=(5, 100), dtype=float)

# computations
data -= (data[2] + 1e-15)  # add epsilon to avoid division by 0
data -= data.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)  # center data
corrcoef_ = da.corrcoef(rec)
std_ = rec.std(axis=1)

# code in question
pp_rec = da.to_zarr(rec, r1, compute=False)

_, corrcoef_, std_ = da.compute(pp_rec, corrcoef_, std_, optimized_graph=True)
```

RuntimeError: Cannot store into in memory Zarr Array using the Distributed Scheduler.

The above code Produces an `RunTimeErrer: Cannot store into in memory Zarr Array using the Distributed Scheduler.`.

```
RuntimeError          Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 9>()
      6 corrcoef_ = da.corrcoef(rec)
      7 std_ = rec.std(axis=1)
----> 9 pp_rec = da.to_zarr(rec, r1, lock=True, compute=True, return_stored=False)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sept22/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/array/core.py:3540, in to_zarr(arr, url, component, storage_options, overwrite, region, compute, return_stored, **kwargs)
   3536 z = url
   3537 if isinstance(z.store, (dict, MutableMapping)) and config.get(
   3538     "scheduler", ""
   3539 ) in ("dask.distributed", "distributed"):
-> 3540     raise RuntimeError(
   3541         "Cannot store into in memory Zarr Array using "
   3542         "the Distributed Scheduler."
   3543     )
   3545 if region is None:
   3546     arr = arr.rechunk(z.chunks)

RuntimeError: Cannot store into in memory Zarr Array using the Distributed Scheduler.
```

Starting from this code, I am failing to translate it into a distributed environment since I can not use `da.to_zarr` directly. Is there any Trick I am not aware of?

What works is to get three individual Futures. However, I was wondering if any optimizations are still existing since relevant intermediate results for the std and corrcoef can be calculated on the fly, when subtracting etc.

```py
cluster = LocalCluster(memory_limit="4GiB", n_workers=4)  # local test cluster
client = Client(cluster)

# code in question
f_cc, f_std, f_rec = client.compute((corrcoef_, std_, rec), optimize_graph=True)
r1[:] = client.result(rec)
corrcoef_ = client.result(f_cc)
std_ = client.result(f_std)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Mainly not calculating the standard deviation and the correlation coefficient from scratch?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you trying to write to disk? I’m confused what your goal is. And I’m confused what is stopping you from using dask distributed. Could you clarify exactly what the issue/question is?

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear. I added the Traceback of the error and yes I want to write back a larger file to disk.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you use xarray for this? Xarray+dask is really good at writing to zarr stores from distributed datasets or dataarrays. I’ve never actually worked with zarr stores directly while trying to sync across processes like this - I expect just switching to xarray will make this a whole lot easier.

Comment: I tried xarray after your comment and it worked. I wanted to stick in dask.arrays since I want to do some computations, which are only supported via dask. However I found my mistake. I will update my question the next dasys! Thanks!

Comment: sounds good. dask is definitely a great tool! that said, xarray should be able to leverage any dask.array feature, since dask.array is the backend used for any chunked arrays - see https://xarray-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dask.html. if you want to manipulate the dask.array under the hood of a DataArray directly, you can access the `da.data` attribute. so I'd still recommend using xarray for working with dask and zarr. feel free to ask another question if you have any usage questions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone ever stumbles over the same problem. The solution is quite simple, but took me some time to understand.

The key is to use a [Zarr-Storage](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/storage.html) option that allows multi-processing and not just multi-threading. Since the [in-memory storage](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/storage.html#zarr.storage.MemoryStore) option is only thread-safe, it will cause some errors as soon as you use Dask.Distributed with multiple processes (see above).

By changing the zarr storage to a [DirectoryStore](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/storage.html#zarr.storage.DirectoryStore) everything works fine.
A possible solution is:

```py
import dask.array as da
import dask.distributed as dd
import zarr

with dd.LocalCluster() as cluster:
    with dd.Client(cluster) as client:
        test_array = da.random.random((100, 100))
        zstore = zarr.DirectoryStore('./example.zarr')
        test_array.to_zarr(zstore)
```

Comment: I have a question about that:  I'm using Zarr with a DirectoryStore for a whole hierarchical collection off data, and trying to dump a dask array to a single dataset in a group in the store, and I'm hitting the same problem.  Did you learn anything about whether / why that's (im)possible?

Comment: have you tried to set the group with the `component=` keyword explicitly?

Comment: No, I honestly didn't see that; I was trying to use the zarr dataset object directly.  Anyway, at least for now I find that dask is performing worse than manually-designed parallelization, so it's potentially moot.